# Hostgator - My http://IP/~USERNAME/ url show me ever 404 error page

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, host

I have a reseller account in Hostgator, I create an account, but when I click in the url for view the site:

http://IP/~USERNAME/

The server show me 404 error page, I upload my site to the `public_html` folder, but the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

Hostgator disabled this option for resellers (i cant beleive they did that!). 
You can use the [virtual hosts plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-hosts/aiehidpclglccialeifedhajckcpedom?hl=en), or edit your hosts file.